# How can I save a Outlook Message from Clipboard to a file?

Tags: c#, outlook, clipboard, msg

If I select an Outlook message from my Inbox and copy it to the clipboard I can paste it as an *.msg file to the Desktop.

Now I want to implement the same feature to my application.

The Clipboard object contains the following elements:

```
RenPrivateSourceFolder
RenPrivateMessages
RenPrivateItem
FileGroupDescriptor
FileGroupDescriptorW
FileDrop
FileNameW
FileName
FileContents
Object Descriptor
System.String
UnicodeText
Text
```

`FileGroupDescriptor` contains a `MemoryStream` with the filename (Subject.msg) but I don't know how to create a copy from the outlook message from the Clipboard data, since none of the elements seem to contain the message itself.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example: [Outlook Drag and Drop in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/outlook_drag_drop_in_cs.aspx). The article works with drag and drop but it should be similar if not identical for working with clipboard.

Comment: That totally works, thanks mate, I searched the whole internet for an example but missed that page because Clipboard is not in the article.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this will work,
but you have to do something like:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText(System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat.Text))
{
    IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)data.GetData(DataFormats.Text, true);
}
```

Comment: You can't cast a string to Outlook.MailItem. This is not an answer to the question.